# Getting invalidrequest error in http action

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

After recurrence trigger http action is taken
By following some documents created url and given it in http action URI

Then after save run the Logicapps and getting error in http action saying that

**Badrequest**

Status code 400
Error: Invalid request

Invalid request error in http action

Comment: Can you provide full code or screenshots

Comment: @Shivvvdevg it would be great if you provide more details like the method and Uri format of your http action/ error image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing issue from my end getting below results.

As per your requirement taken recurrence trigger then http action.

- In http action i have taken **Method** as **Post** and the generated URI as shown in below image.
  [image]
- If i ran the workflow getting below **Invalid request** error  and **status code 400** in http action.
  [image]
- Then I changed **Method** type to **GET** and my workflow ran successfully with status code 200 as shown in below workflow image.

[image]
[image]

- Generally, HTTP action returns the error message "Invalid request" with a status code of 400, indicating that the request sent to the endpoint is invalid. **This may be the result of a number of factors, including an invalid URL, wrong headers, an incorrect body, or an incorrect authentication**.
- So once check with above factors also if Metod is not causing error in your case.

Reference Http action Ms [document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#error-handling)